# Toolbar fades out after a second in iOS 11

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, toolbar

I'm just starting out on a new app with Xcode 9 and iOS 11. I placed a Toolbar at the bottom of the view, then added suggested constraints. Inside the toolbar I placed two buttons, "Sites" and "Item".

[image: xcode layout]

When I run the application, the toolbar disappears after a second whenever I launch the app.

[image]

Any idea what's causing this? How do I fix it? There's currently no code added to it, just the elements I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the elements on the **launch screen** instead of the actual first screen of the application.

If you are using the default configuration, search for the storyboard called **Main.storyboard** and put the items you want to show there.